# Complex multi-column unique constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unique-constraint

I have a table with 10 columns but only care about 3 columns for this.  Imagine my table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable ( RowID int IDENTITY(1,1), UserID int, NodeID int, RoleID int )
```

What I need is a constraint that enforces the following: UserID and RoleID need to be unique for each NodeID (i.e. a user cannot have the same role in multiple nodes).  In other words I want to allow

```
INSERT MyTable (UserID, NodeID, RoleID) SELECT 1, 1, 1
```

but not allow

```
INSERT MyTable (UserID, NodeID, RoleID) SELECT 1, 2, 1
```

if the first insert has occurred because that would result in a user having a role in multiple nodes.

Hopefully this is simple and I'm just making it more complex than it needs to be in my brain.

Comment: what about INSERT MyTable (UserID, NodeID, RoleID) SELECT 1, 2, 2?

Comment: I'm fine with a user having two different roles in two different nodes so that would be okay.  Good question. :)

Comment: Then aren't you looking for unique on UserID + RoleID ?

Comment: I am looking for that as well, but only per NodeID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your constraint depends on data in other rows, this rules out a filtered index. IMO a  viable option could be a trigger. Such a trigger could look like something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger ON dbo.Q1
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @userId INT, @Id INT, @roleId INT, @exists INT;

    SELECT TOP 1
            @userId = userID
           ,@roleId = roleID
           ,@Id = Id
    FROM    inserted;    

    SELECT TOP 1
            @exists = Id
    FROM    Q1
    WHERE   userId = @userId
            AND roleID = @roleID AND Id<> @Id;    

    IF ISNULL(@exists, 0) > 0 
        BEGIN           
            -- you would want to either undo the action here when you use an 'after' trigger
            -- because as the name implies ... the after means the record is allready inserted/updated          
            RAISERROR ('No way we would allow this.', 16, 1);
        END
        -- else
        -- begin
            -- another alternative would be to use a instead of trigger, which means the record
            -- has not been inserted or updated and since that type of trigger runs the trigger 'instead of'
            -- updating or inserting the record you would need to do that yourself. Pick your poison ...
        -- end
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

An unique index should enforce your requirements

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Unique] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    [NodeID] ASC,
    [RoleID] ASC
)
```

From the comments I suppose you will need two unique indices

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_User_Node] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    [NodeID] ASC
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_User_Role] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    [RoleID] ASC
)
```

Comment: That's incorrect, perhaps I didn't explain it well enough.  Your solution allows for e.g. 1,1,1 only once, which is good, but it still allows for 1,2,1.

Comment: I am not shure what exactly should be unique, IMHO you would just have to skip one of the fields from the index, most likely RoleID? If not, what are fields behind 1,2,1?

Comment: That's not it either.  A user can belong to more than node as long as the roles are different.  idx_User_Role might be helpful though.  Thanks.